# Does the person who lights the Chanuka candle at Shul make a Shehechiyanu the first night if it's a Friday?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, synagogue, shehecheyanu

Suppose Chanuka started on Friday night. Everyone lights their Menorah prior to coming to Shul. When the person lights the Menora in Shul he already said Shehechiyanu in his house. Should he say it again?

Comment: The bigger question is does he say shehechiyanu again after nightfall: if the bracha is usually on the day as well as the mitzva, then he needs to repeat for the day because he did the mitzva before the day started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Poskim hold he should say Shehechiyanu again as there is a bigger Porsumei Nisah in Shul.

Comment: How does "bigger pirsumei nisa" mandate a 2nd shehecheyanu?

Comment: It appears there was a separate enactment to light in shuls.  (Heard from Rabbi Welcher.)  Separate mitzva, separate bracha.

Comment: Although the Mishna Berura references that the shul lighter, when he goes home, does not make another bracha (except if he is motzi others).  This seems to indicate that shehechiyanu is not a din in the lighting, but a bracha on the general day -perhaps including lighting- that was set at lighting time.  I don't know that this ruling is unanimous.  Also, the logic may not apply in Gershon's case, but the svara needs to be clarified.

Comment: @Shalom So if I only make it to shul on the fourth night, and they ask me to light, do I say shehechiyanu as it is my first time doing this mitzva?